# After I read xlsx file by gspread, It give me "gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound"

Tags: gspread

I have a file, I shared to my service account, but still have the **SpreadsheetNotFound** error.

So, that means cannot share xlsx files to service account?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the different...

After I "Save as Google Sheets", it works fine.

So I think gspread just read **Google Sheets**.

[image]